# How does a single output Keras model behave when given data with several outputs?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

If I create a model with a single output:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

model  = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1)) # <- one single output

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mae')
```

Why can I fit it on data with three output variables:

```
x_data = np.random.rand(1000, 5)
y_data = np.random.rand(1000, 3) # <- three columns

model.fit(x = x_data, y = y_data, epochs = 1) # <- this works?
```

I've done a bit of investigating and it looks like the model's loss is the average of the losses for each of the columns in y_data:

```
e0 = model.evaluate(x_data, y_data[:,0])
e1 = model.evaluate(x_data, y_data[:,1])
e2 = model.evaluate(x_data, y_data[:,2])

eA = model.evaluate(x_data, y_data)

average = (e0+e1+e2)/3
print(average)
print(eA) # average and eA are the same!
```

Gives:

```
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.4504
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.4590
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.4642
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.4579
0.45786773165067035 #<- (e0+e1+e2)/3
0.45786771178245544 #<- eA
```

So has Keras fitted the model using the average of the three columns in the input data as the y variable?

I know this is not necessarily something to worry about (since we shouldn't provide multiple  outputs to a model that only produces one output), but it's strange behaviour that I want to understand. And I think I'd prefer if it threw an error in this situation, in case the wrong y data is provided by accident.

Comment: This is because of `broadcasting`. For ex, mse = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

#the below are equivalent
1. `mse(np.array([1, 2, 3.]), np.array([1.]))`
2. `mse(np.array([1, 2, 3.]), np.array([1., 1., 1.]))`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about broadcasting. So I guess my question then is how does broadcasting from a 3 column array to a 1 column array work? Because my model is expecting a single column of y-variables, but it somehow works when given three columns of y-variables.

Comment: broadcasting is done from a single dimension to the 3 dimension by repeating. check the above code, you will get the same output.

Comment: I understand the code above where `[1]` is broadcast to `[1,1,1]`, but isn't my model broadcasting in the opposite direction? The model is set up for predicting a single output, I give it three outputs, so how does it reduce 3 columns to 1? I suspect that it's averaging the three columns...